# Amazon S3 folder path doesn't seem to affect file uploads

Tags: assets, s3

I'm using the amazon s3 asset source which all connects and works very well, the only trouble is that the assets field folder path is not respected.

I have a bucket called 'client' and in there we have three folders:

- audio
- documents
- images

In my asset field which i want users to upload audio to, i set the file path as 'audio', '/audio', '/client/audio' but when i upload a new file via the entry form, it puts the file at the same level as the three folders.

Any clues as to why this might be happening?